# JEST for Javascript integration tests throwing ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have this requirement of writing integration tests for Javascript code using Jest. But I am seeing ***fetch is not defined*** even though I have node-fetch installed as well. Any idea how can I fix this ?

Here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --testRegex='script/integration-tests/.*(int-test))\\.js?$'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "uglify-js": "3.16.2"
  }
}
```

**/scripts/validator.js**

```
function validate(){
    
    fetch(SOME_UENDPOINT_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    }).then(data => {
        
    });     
}
```

Here is my JEST integration script.

```
const{validate} = require('../scripts/validator');

describe('User validation', () => {

     test('Should authenticate user', ()=>{
         validate();
         //some basic assertion follows
      });   
});
```

Comment: I did below as suggested form one of the SO discussion

npm install --save-dev node-fetch

and then imported node-fetch in validator.js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
With this I am getting below error during the launch of the page
Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use fetch you need to import it first. You can add this statement to the top of validator.js.

[Version 2 of Fetch is compatible with require()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module), so add `const fetch = require('node-fetch')` to the top of validator.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function validate(){
    
    fetch(SOME_UENDPOINT_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    }).then(data => {
        
    });     
}
```

Comment: Hello @Cameron Miller. Thank you for the response. this time I am seeing "Cannot use import statement outside a module" pointing to index.js of node-fetch. is it something to do with babel ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems node-fetch needs to be imported. First import fetch by adding `import fetch from 'node-fetch'` to the top of validator.js

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

function validate(){
    
    fetch(SOME_UENDPOINT_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    }).then(data => {
        
    });     
}
```

Then, add `"type": "module"` to your package.json. Also add the `--experimental-vm-modules` flag to your jest command.

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --experimental-vm-modules --testRegex='script/integration-tests/.*(int-test))\\.js?$'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "uglify-js": "3.16.2"
  }
}
```

Finally, if you wish to run your script with node, you will need to add the `--experimental-modules` flag.

`node --experimental-modules index.js`